# Как можно вызвать функцию PHP несколько раз?

Tags: php

```
function getPassword() {
    $password = getFunction();
    $size = strlen($password);
    $length = 12;

    while($size != $length)
        $password = getFunction();
    return $password;
}
```

Как можно вызывать функцию до тех пор, пока возвращаемая строка($password) не 
будет равна нужной длинны ($length), чтобы позже когда будет нужная строка будет равна нужной длинне

Comment: PHP это вообще не модно. Сейчас JS в тренде! :D

Comment: Где тебе можно дизлайк поставить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу допустить ошибку в синтаксисе (давно не писал на PHP), но по логике я думаю должно быть так:

```
function getPassword() {
    do {
        $password = getFunction();
    } while(strlen($password) != 12);
    return $password;
}
```